Python ctypes to send "Path" datatype to DLL
I have been learning how to use Python ctypes module to run DLLs created with LabVIEW following the C calling conventions. I've had success with integers and strings, but not with filepaths. The header file below shows the argument as Path *FilePath. I've been trying to pass in strings with ctypes.c_char_p and get OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x003A0043
Header file:
#include "extcode.h"
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*!
 * ReadFile
 */
void __cdecl ReadFile(Path *FilePath);

MgErr __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#pragma pack(pop)

Python File:
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\LabVIEW 2016\Misc\DLL Test\Builds\Build2\Build2.dll")

dll.ReadFile.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)
dll.ReadFile.restype = None

FilePath = b"C:\Users\gjacob\Desktop\File Parking\thorlabs order.txt"

dll.ReadFile(FilePath)


What is the definition of Path?  It is not the same thing as char*…

I don't know what the definition of Path is. I assumed it was a C++ or C data type, but maybe not.

Its definition is probably in the extcode.h file. I good IDE usually has a “goto definition” hotkey.

I was not able to find the extcode.h file. I did try using dumpbin to explore the DLL, but not really knowing what I was looking for I didn't find anything useful.

I found some help on the LabVIEW forums, and they said a LabVIEW path cannot be represented by ctypes, so I should switch any "filepath" datatypes to "string" datatypes in my LabVIEW code.

I found extcode.h but Path is defined as a pointer to an opaque type, so yes you have to switch to a char* or similar in your code.
